# bash function with parameters not usable with eval in Msys2

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line-arguments, msys2

I am using Msys2 from PortableApps under Win 10.
The answer to this question (i.e., identification and solution of the problem) may be related to the Unix/Linux part of usage, or to its "adaptation" to Windows via Msys2. I do not know it in advance (otherwise, I would likely have solved it myself!), so I had posted before (now removed) [a similar question in another SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/471008/13792), which reaches a different audience.

I have a shell function defined in `my_fun.sh` as

```
MYAPP=some_executable
function myfun() { echo "MYAPP=${MYAPP}" && ${MYAPP} "$@" ; }
```

i.e., `some_executable` takes options and parameters.
I can run at the command line

```
$ some_executable -3 input.dat output.dat
```

Now if I run from a shell script `myscript.sh`

```
comm="myfun -3 input.dat output.dat"
echo ${comm}
eval ${comm}
```

(with `echo` I make sure the line is what I want)
I get

```
./myscript.sh: line 8: myfun: command not found
```

If I do `export -f myfun` and then `./myscript.sh`
I start getting

```
MYAPP=
environment: -3: command not found
```

which shows the source of the problem (thanks to comment by Kamil M).

In an Ubuntu box, prior to `export -f ...` I get the same error as above.
But `export` fixes the problem.

**What is the cause for this?**
**Is it related to the pure Linux/Bash use, or is parsing, shell expansion, shell inheritance, etc., under Msys2 slightly different?**
**How do I fix this, in a way that the same script works under Msys2 and Ubuntu?**

Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable

Comment: What `#!` interpreter does your script use? Which bash version are you running?

Comment: @grawity - 1) #!/bin/bash 2) 4.4.19(3)-release (i686-pc-msys)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/471008/13792

Comment: `-3: command not found`, so I suspect `MYAPP` is empty. Is it defined in the same script? If not, is it exported?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - You are right. I have to fix that then.

Answer (score 1):

I have to

```
export MYAPP=some_executable
```

in `my_fun.sh`.
Then the other script reads the value of the variable.